# NSFormatter problem: not getting called for the empty string

Tags: cocoa

I have created a custom formatter for my (read-only) table column. It looks like this:

```
- (NSString *)stringForObjectValue:(id)anObject
{ 
  NSAssert([anObject isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] && anObject != nil,
            @"invalid object");

  if ([anObject isEqualToString:@""])
    return @"EMPTY";
  else
    return [anObject stringByAppendingString:@"++"];
}
```

Very simple. The corresponding objects are just strings, so it's an string-to-string formatter. All non-empty string objects are returned with `@"++"` appended to them. Empty string objects should be turned into the `@"EMPTY"` string.

The `@"++"` gets appended to non-empty strings just fine.

The problem is, `@"EMPTY"` never gets shown! My formatter is never called by Cocoa when the underlying object is the empty string. The corresponding row just keeps being empty, instead of showing my requested `@"EMPTY"`.

Any ideas?

Comment: It looks like this issue has something to do with a placeholder string for the NSTextFieldCell. Sadly, it always appears grayed out by default, and I can't seem to be able to customize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried your code. And it works for me. Here's the code (slightly modified):

**For non-empty string:**

```
#import "untitled.h"


@implementation untitled

-(void) theMain
{
    NSLog(@"str: %@", [self callMe]);

}


-(NSString *)callMe
{
    NSString *anObject = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"s"];

    if ([anObject isEqualToString:@""])
        return @"EMPTY";
    else
        return [anObject stringByAppendingString:@"++"];

}
@end
```

**result:**

```
2011-01-04 09:23:10.991 string[410:80f] str: s++
```

**Now try for empty string:**

```
#import "untitled.h"


@implementation untitled

-(void) theMain
{
    NSLog(@"str: %@", [self callMe]);

}


-(NSString *)callMe
{
    NSString *anObject = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@""];

    if ([anObject isEqualToString:@""])
        return @"EMPTY";
    else
        return [anObject stringByAppendingString:@"++"];

}
@end
```

Result:

```
2011-01-04 09:25:42.379 string[441:80f] str: EMPTY
```

So your code is really working. Perhaps you can show us other portion of your code (the one who calls your function perhaps), so we can really spot the trouble. Your code, as posted, is really working.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but you might be running into nil vs null; unless you're totally sure it's an empty string and not null, you can test with something like:

`[anObject isEqual: [NSNull null]]`

It might be simpler to just use `if ([anObject length]==0)` however, as that should catch any case other than being a string of more than one character, if that's your desire.

Comment: Nah, it wasn't [NSNull null]. Yes I could use length == 0 but that doesn't help much here.